# Excepcion no controlada Select en windows Form

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql

Estoy realizando una consulta para conocer el numero de existencias en el inventario, Tengo un inconveniente funciona cuando encuentra registro en tal caso que no me arroja excepcion

> No se puede convertir un objeto DBNull en otros tipos.

esta es mi instrucion

```
SqlConnection cn = Conexion.ObtConexion();
            string query = "SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM Existencias WHERE idVehiculo=@texto AND idSeccion=@seccion;";
            var cmdo = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmdo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@texto", seleccion);
            cmdo.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seccion", seccion);
            int conteo = Convert.ToInt32(cmdo.ExecuteScalar());
            cn.Close();
```

que puedo hacer para que no caiga en la excepcion si no que añada un "cero" en int conteo.

intente hacer lo siguiente, pero no resulto

```
var result = cmdo.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != null)
            {
                int conteo = Convert.ToInt32(cmdo.ExecuteScalar());
                cn.Close();
                labelDisponibilidad.Text = Convert.ToString(conteo);
            }
            else 
            {
                labelDisponibilidad.Text = "0";

            }
```

observen lo que me esta llegando en result

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posible solución es asegurarte de no devolver un `null` desde SQL, por ejemplo cambiando tu consulta a:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(Cantidad), 0) FROM Existencias WHERE idVehiculo=@texto AND idSeccion=@seccion;
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes resolverlo desde la query si usas el `ISNULL`

```
string query = "SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Cantidad), 0) As Cantidad FROM Existencias WHERE idVehiculo=@texto AND idSeccion=@seccion;";
```

entonces el ejecutar el ExecuteScalar() devolvera cero sino hay registros